# Civilization 6 saved game location?

Tags: macos, civilization-6

Where are saved game files stored in the Mac version of Civilization 6?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out. Not exactly user friendly...

Saves are located in `~/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/Saves`

#### Open with Terminal

Open `Terminal` and type `open ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sid\ Meier\'s\ Civilization\ VI/Saves`

#### Open with Finder

Open `Finder` and press `Cmd+Shift+G`, paste `~/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/Saves` and hit Go

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you bought the game through Steam? If you bought the game from the Mac App Store then the **saved game files** are located in `~/Library/Containers/com.aspyr.civ6.appstore/Data/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/Saves/`

and the **benchmark result files** are located in `/Users/albertfilice/Library/Containers/com.aspyr.civ6.appstore/Data/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/Logs/`

(I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation).